# ios Core BlueTooth Pairing to External BLE Device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am making an BLE based application.

As I know Bluetooth Pairing is handling ios internally.

Is there any possiblity to get access over bluetooth pairing request in ios . I am getting pairing request from external BLE Device but i am not able to know whether user is paired or cancelled.
Apps like TI SensorTag and Multitool apps are handling the pairing request when user clicks cancel then these apps disconnects the peripheral.

I am not getting any clue how they are handling the pairing.

Please help me in getting this solved.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had any success in tracking down this solution?

Answer (score 2):

The BLE devices are more then likely handling the cancel on their side. When you click cancel through iOS it does not pair and does not enable encryption. At this point the BLE devices are probably issuing a disconnect because encryption has not been started.

The only time you will see that pairing message is when encryption is being requested.